# How to create this logo effect (transparent borders that override background div color)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image: logo snippet]

I've tried a few things so far, one was to make the entire white menu nav that supposed to go all the way across the top part of the image. However that has been a nightmare trying to get it to work so that it will scale gracefully in css. I'm wondering if there's another method where I can simply have thestandard bootstrap navbar with a white background, and where the navbar-brand (header logo) is, override the navs background color to be transparent in just the section with the logo? I'm a backend dev trying to figure this out so I'm sure I'm making it harder than it need to be. Any suggestions or samples would be greatly appreciated!

//edit: I forgot to include a link to the dev site. Here it is. http://greatescapes.tiltedllc.com/

As was stated in the original version of this post. The main thing I've tried so far is to simply create a very wide image of the logo and the navbar. This works but has been a nightmare to try and keep consistent when creating a responsive behavior.

Here's a sample of the css for the header i'm using.

```
.ge-menu{
    font-family:'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    position:absolute;
    top:40px;
    background-image:url('/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Header-mobile.png');
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:top;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:100%;
    height:280px;
    margin-top:-10px;
    z-index:100;
}
```

Comment: It's hard to give feedback if you haven't show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Questions seeking help ("why isn't/how to make this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and _**the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**_. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: I've added a link to the dev site. And further explanation. What is on the dev site now is what I've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not perfect, but here's a start.  Basically just use `transform: skew(-45deg);` on a few elements, and put space between them.  Doing this as separate elements it probably easiest

```css
body {
  background: #CCC;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  border-top: 20px solid #57bc90;
}

.split-bar {
  background: #FFF;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  transform: skew(-45deg);
}

#split-bar-left {
  margin-left: -35px;
}
#logo-bar {
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #014039;
  transform: skew(-45deg);
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-right: 60px;
}

#logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 210px;
  top: 50px;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="split-bar" id="split-bar-left"></div>
  <div id="logo-bar"></div>
  <h1 id="logo">Logo</h1>
  <div class="split-bar" id="split-bar-right"></div>
</header>
```

EDIT: On thinking about this a bit more, you could probably just have that `#logo-bar` element and use the `::before` and `::after` of that to create the white bar BGs

Comment: This looks promising, I'll give it a go. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `transform` to rotate your container

```css
.container-logo {
background: grey;
transform: rotate(-45deg);
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
}
.logo {
position: absolute;
transform: rotate(45deg);
right: 100px;
top: 50px;
color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-logo">
  <div class="logo">
    logo
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To create that navbar, you might want to start from 4 elements.

1. Left side white bar
2. Right side white bar
3. Green rectangle
4. Logo

---

Start up by placing the white bars.
Use an `:after` in css on the first bar (to create a triangle behind it).
Use a `:before` in css on the other bar (to create a triangle in front of it).

Next up you place the green rectangle between the two bars and rotate it.

And to end, you place `logo.png` on top of the green rectangle. Make sure it has a transparant background.

---

For as far responsive elements go, it depends on what you want to happen.
If you need more info or even help, let me know.